# SCCM 2012 and WSUS...missing Schema folder

Tags: wsus, sccm, sccm-2012

A few months ago I installed SCCM 2012 R2 on a brand new 2012 R2 box. Everything went smoothly...or so it seems. I attempted to install WSUS to make it work with SCCM. A few hours of struggling later, I thought I had a working install.

Wrong again.

Turns out, the `C:\Program Files\Update Services\Schema` folder is nowhere to be found. Searching has found running the post install again may work, but it didn't appear. Updates haven't been working since around the install date.

What would be the next step? I can't reinstall SCCM as a whole because I have Endpoint Protection deployed to all of our PCs.

Edit: Here is the line from WCM.log that pointed out this error:

> PublishApplication(8427071A-DA80-48C3-97DE-C9C528F73A2D) failed with
>   error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of
>   the path 'C:\Program Files\Update
>   Services\Schema\baseapplicabilityrules.xsd'.~~   at -big long string of crap-
>
> $$<04-01-2014
>   13:59:57.336+240> Done using CORP\Administrator
>   credentials~  $$<04-01-2014
>   13:59:57.336+240> ERROR: Failed to publish sms
>   client to WSUS, error = 0x80070003 
>   $$<04-01-2014
>   13:59:57.336+240>

Edit2: Had the idea of firing up my old WSUS server (running 2008R2) and copying the missing folder over, but that didn't work either:

> PublishApplication(8427071A-DA80-48C3-97DE-C9C528F73A2D) failed with
>   error System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wsus/2005/04/CorporatePublishing/UpdateServicesPackage.xsd:File'
>   cannot contain child element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wsus/2005/04/CorporatePublishing/SoftwareDistributionPackage.xsd:AdditionalDigest'
>   because the parent element's content model is empty.~~~

Answer (score 1):

I had the same/similar problem. My schema, tools and API folder were missing from C:\Program Files\Update Services. I reinstalled WSUS several times but they never appeared after installation.

But I found the solution/problem. When removing WSUS, I found that it didn't remove ALL of the features that are installed when you install WSUS on a fresh server. While removing the WSUS features (or after if you already have), you will have to manually remove the following:

Features\Remote Server Administration Tools\Role Administration Tools\Windows Server Update Services Tools\API and PowerShell cmdlets

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8xG6.png)

When you install WSUS next, it will reinstall this feature properly.

Breakdown of what I did:

1. Remove WSUS features
2. Remove API and PowerShell cmdlets (can be done with step 1)
3. Remove WSUS IIS Site
4. Restart Server
5. Install WSUS Features. You should see the API and PowerShell cmdlets listed in the Confirmation page when installing the features. (This was usually missing)
6. Configure WSUS as required.

This resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try my method but there is no guarantee.

Firstly, search for baseapplicabilityrules.xsd file on C:\ directory and it will find a folder location for you then copy all items in this folder into Program Files\Update Files\Schema, if schema folder doesn't exist, you can create it manually.

Good luck!

Comment: Doing this results in the error I described above...it doesn't like the file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your WSUS server role did not install properly.  Follow the below steps to remove the SUP and the WSUS role and re-add them:

1. Remove the Software Update Point role via ConfigMgr
2. remove the WSUS server role from your WSUS server
3. Re-add the WSUS server role to the WSUS server
4. Reinstall the Software Update Point role

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I confirmed Beau's detailed assessment.  I then noticed in the original post that copying from the "old server" didn't work because the OS version mismatch.  I compared 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 and 2016 and confirmed as expected most files are different for OS version.

I successfully installed WSUS on a new server running the same OS and then copied the API and Schema folders to my SCCM SUP.